# mysql-connector-java need in Redhat 9

Tags: java, jboss, redhat

Trying to place mysql-connector-java.jar for Jboss, getting failed because of depends. Below is the error can you please help me.

```
#sudo rpm -ivh /home/mysql-connector-j-8.0.31-1.el9.noarch.rpm
home/
[root@ip-10-0-5-172 ~]# sudo rpm -ivh /home/ec2-user/mysql-connector-j-8.0.31-1.el9.noarch.rpm
warning: /home/ec2-user/mysql-connector-j-8.0.31-1.el9.noarch.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 3a79bd29: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        java-headless >= 1:1.8.0 is needed by mysql-connector-j-1:8.0.31-1.el9.noarch
```

Install Java Version:
`# java -version openjdk version "1.8.0_352" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_352-b08) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.352-b08, mixed mode)`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/id3Pz.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you are doing, but JBoss *itself* doesn't require MySQL drivers.  So presumably you are trying to setup some webapp or enterprise app that uses a MySQL database backend.

On the flipside, the MySQL drivers do not require a specific Java install.   Any Java 8 or later release should be suitable.  So you should be able to install that RPM using the `--nodeps` option ... telling it to ignore the dependencies declared by the RPM.

It is unclear why you (apparently) didn't install OpenJDK Java 8 from the RedHat package repositories using the package manager.  If you had done that, then the package manager (`yum` or `dnf`) *should know* that Java 8 was installed and the dependency was satisfied.  More important, the package manager will be able to tell you when an updated Java 8 package was available from the RedHat repos.

(Or maybe you *did* install OpenJDK using the package manager, but you just "need" to install the "headless" version.  I think that the package name would be "java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless".)